# How to return an array of books and subtitles where one column will show the unique books and the second column the unique subtitles for those books

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this range of books and subtitles:

| BOOK | SUBTITLE |
| --- | --- |
| BR | ELE |
| BR | INT |
| BR | PI |
| BR | INT |
| BR | PI |
| EF | ELE |
| EF | INT |
| EF | INT |

I want to create a list like this:

| BOOK | SUBTITLE |
| --- | --- |
| BR | ELE |
|  | INT |
|  | PI |
| EF | ELE |
|  | INT |

I want to do it with either one formula or one formula at the top of each column.

I've managed to do it in two steps with the following:

Original range: A2:B9

In cell D2:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$9, $A2, $B$2:$B$9, $B2)=1, $A2, "")
```

In cell E2:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2, $A2, $B$2:$B2, $B2)=1, $B2, "")
```

Then in cell G2:

```
=FILTER(D2:E27,E2:E27<>"")
```

Also, I've managed it by these formulas. In cell D2:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(A2:B10),1,TRUE,2,TRUE)
```

In cell G2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D7=D1:D6, "", D2:D7))
```

In cell H2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(E2:E7)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use REDUCE to loop inside the unique books, and stack the unique values of the filtered subtitles:

```
=REDUCE(A1:B1,TOCOL(UNIQUE(A2:A),1),LAMBDA(a,v,IFNA(
  VSTACK(a,
   HSTACK(v  ,  UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=v)))))))
```

[image]

Comment: This works a treat and the original list also doesn't have to be sorted first - Thank you!!